# .Net Core 3.1/Standard 2.1 NU1101 for ALL packages

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget-package

"NU1101 Unable to find package . No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Users..."

I started having this problem in my blazor app and I cannot seem to find a fix.  Nothing seems to work...

I run .Net Core 3.1 w/ Standard 2.1.
This does not happen in Framework apps.
I have eliminated all config and json files from the branch as possible issues.
I can list packages in the package manager, but I cannot install from there or command line (or even execute a dotnet restore).
This was first noticed last month (12/20) with no recent changes having been applied.
NU1101 is the error every time. Noticeably, it always says it cannot restore from the solution folder, which is not indicated anywhere.
I have modified the nuget.config to include:

```xml
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="./packages" />
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="./packages" />
  </config>
  <settings>
    <repositoryPath>./packages</repositoryPath>
  </settings>
```

No joy no matter what I try.

Comment: Could you please share the whole error message? Have you checked the NuGet configuration identifies the package sources is the right one? More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1101).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that, in Visual Studio 2019 when upgrading 3 projects to .Net Standard 2.1 (from 2.0) a line was added to the csproj files which caused them to fail at the project level restore.  restorePath had a fictitious variable in it.  I deleted the entire entry and it all worked fine.
In case someone else comes across this, edit the csproj file directly to fix.